# Curvature and torsion of a spherical curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, spheres, arc-length

I'm trying to show that if $\alpha$ is a regular curve parametrized by arc lenght whose range lies on the unit sphere centered at the origin, then $\kappa (s) = \sqrt{1+j^2}$ and $\tau (s) = \dfrac{j'(s)}{1+j^2(s)}$

where $j(s)=\det[\alpha (s), \alpha '(s), \alpha ''(s)]$. Any ideas?

Comment: Tip: the MathJax should be wrapped by "$".

Comment: l edited your post to properly $\LaTeX$ify it.  Mathjax likes its $\LaTeX$ to be enclosed in "\$" signs, not single quotation marks.  Good question, ***+1***.  Cheeers!

Comment: I did the same thing as @RobertLewis…

Comment: I edited the post, thanks for the advice!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098471/speed-of-curve-on-a-sphere/2098690#2098690.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that since $\alpha$ is parametrized by arc length, we have $T=\alpha'$, and $\alpha'' = \kappa N$. Then $\alpha = aT+bN+cB$, for some $a,b,c$. However, note that $a=0$, since $\alpha$ has unit length, so the tangent vector is always orthogonal to $\alpha$. Thus $\alpha = bN+cB$, with $b^2+c^2=1$. Then we can differentiate and apply [the Frenet-Serret formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) to get
$$\alpha' = (-\kappa b)T +(b' -\tau c)N + (c'+\tau b)B = T,$$
so we get the equations
$$1=-\kappa b,\quad b'=\tau c,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,c' = -\tau b.$$

Then taking the determinant 
$$\det (\alpha,\alpha', \alpha'') = \det(\alpha,T,\kappa N) = \kappa c \det(B,T,N) = \kappa c.$$

Observe that $1=1^2=\kappa^2b^2$, and $j^2 =\kappa^2 c^2$, so $$1+j^2 = \kappa^2(b^2+c^2)=\kappa^2,$$
so $\kappa = \sqrt{1+j^2}.$

As for $\tau$, note that $$c = \frac{j}{\sqrt{1+j^2}}.$$
Differentiating, we get
$$c' = j'\frac{\sqrt{1+j^2}-j^2/\sqrt{1+j^2}}{1+j^2}= \frac{j'\kappa(1- c^2)}{1+j^2} = \frac{j'\kappa b^2}{1+j^2}.$$

Then recalling the equations we derived before, $\kappa b = -1$, $c'=-\tau b$, we obtain
$$-\tau b = -\frac{j'b}{1+j^2},$$ 
so
$$ \tau = \frac{j'}{1+j^2},$$
as desired.